# NSDateFormatter

Tags: uitableview, ios, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to create a TableViewCell like the one in the Notes app on the iPhone. Have the title on the left and the time on the right next to the discloser indecator.

A tableView which would look like that. I know I have to use something like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"HH:mm zz"];

NSDate *dateTmp;
dateTmp = [[self.Notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"CDate"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate: dateTmp];
```

http://cl.ly/3Mpj

How would I move the detail label to the top next the the discloser indecator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use should create a custom cell... 
Place two buttons accordingly...
Here i did like this...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you still want the time to be the detail label? If so the first option could work..

There are a few options:

You could try to simply set the detailLabel's text alignment with something like `cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight`

Or if this doesn't fit your needs, you can always subclass `UITableViewCell` and create your own cell with placement however you need it.

Edit: on rereading your post, you want the time Label to be on the same "row" as the name, and on the right..for this you are probably going to want to use a custom `UITableViewCell`, that way you can place and format your labels exactly how you want them.